ServiceUnavailable: Unable to retrieve routing information
I am trying to connect to my Neo4j database, but I encountered an error. Could anyone assist me?I will be very grateful.
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "***"
os.environ["NEO4J_URI"] = "neo4j+ssc://c48f666c.databases.neo4j.io"
os.environ["NEO4J_USERNAME"] = "neo4j"
os.environ["NEO4J_PASSWORD"] = "***"

Failed to read from defunct connection ResolvedIPv4Address(('34.66.78.163', 7687)) (ResolvedIPv4Address(('34.66.78.163', 7687)))
Unable to retrieve routing information
ServiceUnavailable: Unable to retrieve routing information

